# Pinning a specific folder to the taskbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I "pin" my "Documents" folder to the Windows taskbar in Windows 7?

I have Explorer pinned in my taskbar but when clicked, it opens by default my "Libraries" directory and not the desired "Documents" directory.

Comment: This isn't programming related, but just pin it to Explorer then right click Explorer to see your pinned folders.

Comment: FYI: If you want to do this with "Computer" (ie. open with a list of drives), create a shortcut to `%systemroot%\explorer.exe /e,::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}` in the start menu, and then pin that (the GUID is the id of the computer node in the Windows Shell namespace).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just drag the link to your `Documents` folder to the task bar.  It will show up as a link to start the `Windows Explorer` but you will see the `Documents` folder listed as one of the pinned folders in the jump list.

If you wish to force the link to open to the folder directly, you can modify the shortcut to open the folder of your choice.  Just right click on the link, right click on the `Windows Explorer` shortcut and go to properties.  Then add the path to your folder in the target.  You could use `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` in this case.

[image]

Comment: Sadly you can't edit properties from the Taskbar, so you'll need to navigate to the Taskbar file system location in Windows Explorer and edit your shortcut's properties there: `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on desktop,
- Select new text document,
- Name it whatever you want.exe, for example; `My Documents.exe` or `music.exe`,
- Left click on desktop and select yes at the "Are you sure you want to do this" window that comes up,
- Right click on newly created file and select `Pin to taskbar`,
- Go to the location of the file and hold shift and right click on the file and select copy as path,
- Right click on new item on task bar and select `properties`, `delete` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or paste into target box,
- Select `apply` and `ok`.

You can also change the name in the general tab and change the icon, there are some decent icon sets out there.

This works for most all folders.
I think I found this info at sevenforums.