# Dropbox installed, but don't see any folder for it

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I installed Dropbox latest version from: http://www.dropbox.com/install

But after the installation was completed, I see now folder or network drive in my Windows Explorer. (I have Windows 7 - 32 bit version). Even when I click of the dropbox icon created after installation, nothing happens.

1. Are there any known issues with Windows 7?
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a folder *My Dropbox* or *Dropbox* on your user directory (i.e. the parent directory of e.g. *My Documents*)? Can't you right-click on the tray icon for Dropbox and select *Open Dropbox Folder* or something like that?

Comment: No, in my Windows Mydocuments dir. there is no Dropbox folder.

Comment: Is it needed to restart the PC ?

Comment: Not *in* My Documents, next to it. As in, sibling, not child!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click the Dropbox icon in your system tray and select preferences. Open the "advanced" tab and there should be an indication of where Dropbox thinks your folder is. If it's incorrect or missing, you can just select "change", enter a new folder and it should start syncing immediately.

Comment: @Yes. I noticed the icon! thanks. Configured the account, dropbox folder and its working now.

Comment: @goldenmean: If this answer solved your problem, you should **accept** it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

yay Dropbox!!

right click on the icon in tray and select "Open Dropbox folder". top of the list.

also go to C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin and right click on the Dropbox.`.`.exe`` and pin to taskbar. delete the icon from your desktop...nice and clean

you can pin the Dropbox folder to the taskbar. see this for instructions...

[Pinning a specific folder to the taskbar in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/237407/window-7-pin-specific-folder-to-taskbar/279033#279033)